# php изменить elements xml

Tags: php, массивы, xml

есть такой лист хмл

```
 <AnketaList>
    <user_list>
    <last_name Name="lastname">Margaryan</last_name>
    <first_name Name="firstname">Xachik</first_name>
    <password Name="password">asdf</password>
    <email Name="email">xch@mail.ru</email>
    <photo Name="photo">userphoto/avatar-default.png</photo>
    <date Name="photo">1565168998</date>
    </user_list>
    <user_list>
    <last_name Name="lastname">Sargsyan</last_name>
    <first_name Name="firstname">Aram</first_name>
    <password Name="password">asdf</password>
    <email Name="email">aedfg@ert.ert</email>
    <photo Name="photo">userphoto/avatar-default.png</photo>
    <date Name="photo">1565169278</date>
    </user_list>
    <user_list>
    <last_name Name="lastname">Asatran</last_name>
    <first_name Name="firstname">Rustam</first_name>
    <password Name="password">asdfg</password>
    <email Name="email">rust@mail.ru</email>
    <photo Name="photo">userphoto/avatar-default.png</photo>
    <date Name="photo">1565169324</date>
    </user_list>
    </AnketaList>
```

хочу чтобы изменил например password на имени rustam и потом сохранит, в интернету посмотрел не нашло подобно (

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться  simpleXML

```
xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
$el = $xml->xpath('//user_list[first_name="rustam"]/password');
// Xpath вернет массив (по-хорошему, надо проверить, что он не пустой)
// Берем первый элемент
$el[0][0] = "New Password";
echo $xml->asXML();
```

Comment: http://my-beybi.ru/test.php попробовал так не работает (

Comment: $str правильно задали, без начальных пробелов? `$str = '<AnketaList>` и тд

Comment: Работал но не менял значение http://my-beybi.ru/test.php

Comment: @ЖораХзмалян поменяйте в имени первую букву на большую first_name="Rustam"